# android flipper running on emulator but not on device

Tags: android

Xml file have 16 images in one flipper using imageview.

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/c" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/d" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/e" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/f" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/g" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/h" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/i" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/j" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/k" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/l" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/m" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/n" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView15"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/o" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/p" />                

</ViewFlipper>
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ViewFlipper Flippy;

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Flippy=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    Flippy.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

```
Flippy.showNext();
```

}

}

Not Working on Device it Stopped